# ModuleNotFoundError and no main_globals

Tags: python

when trying to run and app today, instead of it running I had some errors thrown.

Usually when I've had errors w/ python I can set new PATH or something and it works again. But this time nothing I've tried works.

The app still works on my other computer, running the same OS.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts\snscrape.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snscrape'
```

Comment: Have you updated your python version?

Comment: looks like you have both python 3.10 and 3.9 there

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pip3.10 install snscrape
```

---

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snscrape'` implies one of the following:

- You don't have this module installed
- Don't have it installed on your specific Python version
- It can't be found